# Stop Material-UI's Select Popover from changing position

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) to render a multi-select element.

Currently the `Popover` moves when items are selected, like this:

[image]

I actually think this is—unfortunately—the desired behaviour, as it also [does this in the example given in their documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select).

Is there any way to **disable** this annoying behaviour, so that the Popover has a **fixed** position **below** the `Select` input?